# why does c++ map find() have logarithmic complexity?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, stdmap

If I understand correctly, because std::map uses a binary tree to maintain its sorting, it has logarithmic complexity lookup. Why then is it not implemented using a hash table like `std::unordered_map`?

What would be the downside of creating my own data structure that is an unordered map where the values are nodes in a linked list?
Insertion would be a binary search through the list using the unordered map keys, and to retrieve data from a node I would access it using the unordered map key with constant time.
And if this makes sense, is there a simpler solution?

Edit: adding some context
for my use case I need a structure that stores Items, which each have a price and a unique ID, such that they are ordered by price, and that sorting should be maintained when adding or removing an item.
My initial idea was to store them in a vector and to have a separate unordered_map which maps each ID to a in iterator to the vector, this way I can remove items from the vector with **constant** time, and add items with logarithmic time, which cannot be escaped due to the sorting.
I now know this doesn't work because the vector iterators would get invalidated when adding or removing Items.
So I need a stable data structure (probably not contiguous in memory) that has indexing and can be sorted, which is why I thought I could use a map while retaining O(1) lookup.

Comment: Why would you want logarithmic insertion when `std::unordered_map` already has O(1) amortized insertion?

Comment: [`std::unordered_map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) _"...Constant on average, __worst case linear in the size of the container__...."_.  Where as [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) is always _"...Logarithmic in the size of the container..."_  ie it all depends on the data being inserted.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat because I want the data to be sorted

Comment: In the end you should verify performance on your data with measurements.

Comment: Maps are not sorted data to begin with (and not contiguous in memory). So what do you mean by "sorted"?

Comment: @RichardCritten worst case is only if there are a lot of collisions with the hashing right? should I be concerned with that if I'm not inserting a huge amount?

Comment: How do you propose implementing `std::map`'s requirements of an ordered container by using your hash tables?

Comment: Do you mean an ordered map based on a hash table? That's impossible. That's the downside. Do you mean an unordered map based on a binary tree? That's much worse than the current implementation. Your question and title contain multiple different questions. That makes your whole question unclear.

Comment: To answer the question's title: "_why does c++ map find() have logarithmic complexity?"_ you have this backwards - `std::map::find` is required by the C++ Standard to have logarithmic complexity - how this is implemented is up to each library team and a red-black tree is one obvious choice.

Comment: The key is in the name: "unordered".  You can't do a binary search on an unordered list.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Mathematical maps might not be sorted, in general, but the standard C++ `map` is ordered. It supports iterating through it in order, so the implementation has to maintain some internal sorting (such as a tree structure) to provide the required iterator performance. That is what OP means by sorted for this; the internal implementation must retain ordering information.

Comment: Note that a binary search through a linked list inefficient, since you loose the possibility of random access, even if your list is sorted. This means you're better off using linear search, since it's simpler to implement and likely more efficient.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what if I use a set for insertion, get the iterator for that insertion, and use it as a value in an unordered_map? I understand that the space complexity would be horrible.

Comment: Consider nonstandard maps, such as btree from https://github.com/greg7mdp/parallel-hashmap

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for that feedback. I should have guessed that for std::map.

Comment: It is hard to pinpoint the flaw in your proposed data structure because you have not described it in a detailed enough manner, but it seems like you think that if you combine a search tree (or a sorted array good for a binary search) and a hash table, you will get the best of both worlds. In reality you will get the worst of both worlds. Try to write some code and see for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

> What would be the downside of creating my own data structure that is
> an unordered map where the values are nodes in a linked list?
> Insertion would be a binary search through the list using the
> unordered map keys, and to retrieve data from a node I would access it
> using the unordered map key with constant time. And if this makes
> sense, is there a simpler solution?

There is no way to get around the fact that inserting into an ordered, comparison-based associative container is an O(log n) operation. For proof, note that if you could insert into such a container in O(1) time then you could perform a comparison-based sort in O(n) time by copying items into the container and then copying them back out in sorted order.

Because of this, it is unclear exactly what you are proposing. Certainly there are situations in which it makes sense to maintain a hash table on some key *k* to the values of a binary tree that does not use *k* as its key; for example, if you want records of people ordered by name but also be able to find records by phone number in constant time. This sort of thing does not get around that searching by name will be O(log n) though. You are just maintaining two associative containers but saving space by sharing value records. There's nothing magical about this.

Comment: I understand that insertion into a sorted container would have to be O(log n). What I am having difficulty understanding is the lookup time. I thought since a map draws a connection between a key and a value it would have O(1) lookup, again, no iteration over the elements, exactly like unordered map does it.

Comment: maps in C++ are typically implemented as red-black trees. When you look up an item in one the implementation id performing a binary search which O(log n)

Comment: @Mishu666 It isn't clear what you mean by "a map draws a connection between a key and a value". How do you think this connection is realized in practice?

Comment: to my understanding it uses a hash function that turns objects that have the type of the key into one that has the type of the value, ideally no two keys give the same value. So if I do ```my_map[k]``` it should just compute ```hash(k)``` and give me the return value.

Comment: @Mishu666 Nothing like that happens in reality. `std::map` uses the comparison function (which is one of its template parameters) to search in the tree. It doesn't use any kind of hash. What makes you think that it makes sense or even possible to insert in a tree and retrieve using a hash? In order to use a hash, you need to compute it on insertion, but then you have a regular old hash table (IOW the `unordered_map`) and you don't need a tree at all.